# Defining a datasource resource in tomcat context.xml

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, resources, datasource

I'm using Spring batch and spring batch admin and i write in applicationContext this code, defining a bean called `dataSource`:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" ... />
```

Now, i would change this code, defining my "`dataSource`" in the `context.xml` file of Tomcat and then load it.

I read that this is possible defining a Resource like this:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/myDatabase"
        password="myPass" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host.com:1521/abc" username="myUser" />
```

and then loading it in my `applicationContext.xml` using this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myDatabase" />
```

But with this i have a problem. It is possible to define a resource for my dataSource so that it is of class `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and not `javax.sql.DataSource`?

Any help?

Thank you